# Onclick event won't recognise function

Tags: javascript, events

Using Javascript. I'm getting an error when the onclick of a button fires (by pressing the button).  The error is:

`Uncaught TypeError: accept is not a function at HTMLInputElement.onclick`

Here's the HTML of the button (and its neighbour):

```
<input type="button"  value="Accept Offer" onclick="accept()" />
<input type="button"  value="Cancel" onclick="cancelAccept()" />
```

The `Cancel` button works fine.

Here's the `accept` JS function:

```
function accept() {
    //check that user logged in
    api.me()
    .then( (res) => {   //logged in, accept offer
        acceptOffer(res.user);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log("error:",err);
        alert("Authentication error. Please logout and in again");
        cancel();
    });
}
```

The javascript is imported(?) in the head tag at the top of the html page.
`api.me()` is a call to a library.

Comment: What is the structure of your HTML page? Where is your script? Is it connected to the page?

Comment: Is that function visible in the global scope?

Comment: Make sure that `accept` exists in the global scope

Comment: It's in the global scope.

Comment: It is not a system function, you've just overridden `accept` with another value, which is not a function. Open the console, and write "accept" to the console, and hit enter, what do you see?

Comment: @Teemu it responds with: `ƒ`

Comment: The best advice you can get: stop messing with globals, in practice they are never needed, unless you've some cross-window scripting.

Comment: Rename accept , it works . dont know why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the name `accept` is causing trouble. See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8s41jxzq/1/).

Rename your function and put it in the global scope.

Comment: That's it.  Is it a system function?

Comment: It only happens with input-elements, because the input element has an attribute of "accept". Use any other element like <button> or <a> and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to change the name of the function as "accept" could be misinterpreted by JS (it's an html attribute).

Comment: Attribute names are not messing with JS namespace.

Comment: @Teemu apparently they do...somehow. Just did a [quick test](https://jsbin.com/howojabumu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: When using that function name with onclick and an input element there's a problem, using it with a button element seems to work. So it looks like it has to do with the name because "accept" is an attribute of input elements.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the input with button tag 
as this demo

```js
function accept() {  
    //check that user logged in
    api.me()
    .then( (res) => {   //logged in, accept offer
        acceptOffer(res.user);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log("error:",err);
        alert("Authentication error. Please logout and in again");
        cancel();
    });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="accept()">Accept Offer</button>
<button onclick="cancelAccept()">Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below example will produce an error message complaining that accept is not a function.

```js
function accept(){
  console.log("I accept");
  alert(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].accept);
}

function cancelAccept(){
   console.log("I cancel");
}

console.log(accept);
```

```html
<input type="button"  value="Accept Offer" onclick="accept()"  accept="text/html,image/gif" />
<input type="button"  value="Cancel" onclick="cancelAccept()" />
```

What happened is that since the input element has an accept property that created a conflict for the user-defined function accept().

Function shares a name with a pre-existing propertySection

> Sometimes when making a class, you may have a property and a function
>   with the same name. Upon calling the function, the compiler thinks
>   that the function ceases to exist.

Source: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function).